# Zoom an image with jQuery using .offset()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a very simple bit of code. It changes the `max-width` of the image to give the illusion of zooming in. I am using jQuery's `offset()` with the mouse's coordinates so the user can pan the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/YcbDM/

```
$('.image-container img').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css('max-width', '200%');
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        $(this).offset({
             top: e.pageY - 300,
            left: e.pageX - 300   
        });
    });
 });
```

This works exactly as I want it to, however, I'd like the pan to be **reversed**. Currently, if you move your cursor up, you see the bottom half of the image and vice versa. I've tried reversing the offset, like so:

```
             top: e.pageY + 300,
            left: e.pageX + 300
```

But the image is removed from view completely.

If possible I'd like to avoid using a plugin for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` seem to achieve the effect you wanted fairly well

```
$('.image-container img').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).css('max-width', '200%');
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        $(this).offset({
             top: -e.pageY,
            left: -e.pageX

        });
    });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zSjL9/

Comment: That's perfect. How come I have to ignore the container width (so no `-300`)?

Comment: When you are at the outer edge of container (right or bottom), you offset the image by the -(container-width).